# Magento Phishing Attempt

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I got a suspicious email which looked pretty legit today and wanted to share with the community and maybe people who are more security savvy than me can tell me more about this Phishing attempt.

Basically it's an email from a 'customer' who says they have put in the wrong address and add a link to the email to what looks like your own website that looks like:

```
[yourwebsite]/order/view/order_id/key/1ee0a069b22ac438e25ad3acbc4a3bcb/
```

It contains a link to :

```
https://www.magepanel.info/[yourwebsite]/admin?next=https://[yourwebsite]/order/view/order_id/key/02c9bfb2a970ab62ef8643a47e646064
```

Does anyone know what type of exploit this is and what it does if you click it?

Thanks!

Comment: it doesnt do anything.  It takes you to the magepanel.info website with a magento login screen.  They hope that you will type in your login details.  It then saves your website info and login details and kicks you back to the home page of your site.  Pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a simple PHP script to grab your Magento Login Data.

Practically when you enter your magento access data, they are captured and saved in a text file or database. So basically it's an attempt to[pishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing).

Just check the url for good.